# A tool that measures the quality of an audio file for noise (e.g. noise percentage, if it's bearable)

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a tool that can measure the quality of an audio file (a recorded call).

I would like to give it the audio file as input and get data on how much noise is present in the recording.

Comment: Do you have any platform requirements?

Comment: On Linux machines